# Why does CToolTipCtrl parent matters?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, tooltip, gdi

Recently, I've got stuck over strange UI issue, found a solution, but still unsure about problem cause.

**Preconditions**:

MFC MDI application has 2 modeless dialogs opened, both has a child third-party grid and `CToolTipCtrl`. Dialog windows crosses each other borders (i.e. active dialog is overlapping part of inactive one). `CToolTipCtrl` is similar to example, the only tool set for tooltip is grid. Parent of tooltip is There is the corresponding dialog's **grid**, `TTS_ALWAYSTIP` style is set to allow tooltips on inactive dialog.

**Issue**:

When mouse is hovering on *inactive* dialog's grid, tooltip is appearing and inactive dialog is drawn over active one. In other words, inactive window is brought to top without activating. It's drawn completely, including caption, buttons, grid, etc.

I've checked Z-order and found that inactive dialog is still inactive, even when shown on top. No Z-order changed. Then I gathered message log using Spy++ for whole inactive dialog while tooltip is appearing and found no `WM_ACTIVATE`, `WM_FOCUS`, `WM_MDIACTIVATE`, etc. Then I performed search about how to bring window up without activating and logged SetWindowPos calls - the only calls are performed for `CToolTipCtrl`'s window. So, no `SetWindowPos` for dialogs called. No BringToTop() called as well.

**Solution**

I've changed tooltip's parent window from dialog's grid to dialog itself - and that fixed problem. However, I still have no idea what was happened and why changing parent attribute matters.

**Question**

Could anyone give me a hint about what I'm missing? Maybe, tooltip causes repaint of grid, and that repaint has a bug causing repaint over active window, but I haven't found any proofs yet.

Haven't found something specific about tooltip's parent property in MSDN as well. Maybe, I have to read somenting about Windows GDI?